# Iframe with allowtransparency over applet

Tags: javascript, debugging, iframe, applet, transparency

I had made a applet and placed a iframe with allowtransparency over it.

But i cannot click anywhere on the applet because the iframe is "blocking" it. But it shouldn't because of the allowtransprency??? What to do???

```
            <div id="content">
                <div class="humans">
                    <iframe allowTransparency="true" class="humans-frame" id="qcontent" src="inner.php" width="760"
                    height="582" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
                     scrolling="no" style="background:transparent"></iframe>
                    <div class="humans-box">
                        <applet  allowtransparency="true" id="applet" code="main.AvatarClient.class" archive="AvatarClient_40.jar"
                        name="Chat" width="760" height="582" scriptable="true" MAYSCRIPT="true">
                            <param name="cache_option" value="NO">
                            <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                            <param name="localization" value="locDK/"></param>
                            <param name='userName' value='lotta' />
                            <param name='password' value='test1234' />
                        </applet>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: allowtransperency will only allow you to see what is behind parts of the iframe; it's like glass, even though you can see through it you can't click on what's behind it.

What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? There must be a better way of achieving whatever end you want.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `allowtransparency` on the `iframe`, use `clip` to layer the elements as in an unrelated question:

- [CSS3 IE9 click through pseudo-element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868360/css3-ie9-click-through-pseudo-element/12771673#12771673)